# Explain currrent and voltage in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, current

Please help me to understand.According to me if there is no voltage drop across an element the voltage at its trailing end must be same as the supply voltage.[image: Proteus 8 ISIS]
[image]  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW32B.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW32B.png
But in the above simulation there is no voltage drop across R1 and the voltage at its trailing end is shown as 0.23v.the ammeter shows 0A.Without current(I) there will not be any voltage(V).

Comment: Because you have 2 volt meters in series on both side of R2, the R2 is basicly floating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To measure the voltage "at" a point, you need to connect a voltmeter between ground and that point, not put a voltmeter in series with the rest of the circuit.

As drawn, all current through R1 and R2 also has to go through two voltmeters (V2 and V4). Since a voltmeter has very very high resistance, there's very little current flowing through your "circuit". The voltages you measure depend strongly on hidden assumptions of the simulator (like what's the resistance of the voltmeter and whether there's any parasitic conductance to ground from each node).

Comment: They're the potential difference between the two points those meters are connected to. As I said in the answer, the values you see depend on hidden variables. In particular, most simulators will insert high-value resistors from each node to ground in a circuit like this in order to be able to find any solution at all. You can see something strange is going on because the values shown on meters v1, v2, v3, and v4 don't add up to 5 V as KVL says they should.

Comment: Ya........I'm surprisedto see such strange thing.....anyway thanks for clearing my doubts and make me feel happy...